# Setting header -- HTTP/1.0 error text

Tags: php

Can I set a custom text in a header HTTP/1.0, like this:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 400 Custom text for debugging);
```

instead of:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request);
```

I would like to inquire if it's valid. It would be very useful in some cases.